# I need to Learn salesforce LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

As per project requirement I want to learn salesforce LWC where I can learn from scratch can someone please help me where I can get all material for same

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/

Answer (score 3):

The best place to learn the Salesforce platform is [Trailheads](http://trailhead.salesforce.com). '

The modules will provide provide you guided examples and well explained tutorials alongside different scenarios.

Additionally, links towards the documentation are included for additional content and further details related to the learning module.

Answer (score 1):

You can start learning from [Build Lightning Web Components](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-lightning-web-components)

Also,

1. refer my [Salesforce Lightning Web Components Cheat Sheet](https://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2019/07/salesforce-lwc-cheatsheet.html)
2. [Learning Path about Lightning Web Component](https://www.santanuatonline.com/learning-lightning-web-component/)
3. [List of my posts related to Lightning Web Components](https://santanuboral.blogspot.com/p/lightning-web-components.html)

These are enough to learn LWC.